# Some layers of a DWG/DXF drawing lose their coordinates when imported to QGIS

Tags: qgis, autocad

I have a field layout AutoCAD drawing that I can import to QGIS, yet some of the layers do not get the correct position applied.

These layers all appear overlying each other with their centroids at 0,0 rather than their UTM coordinates 650000, 6650000 (approx) where the rest of the drawing layers load in correctly.

I think the layers that are correct have originally been entered in the correct geometry, yet the layers that fail to load in the correct position, were originally complex structural drawings which have been rotated and shifted into their installed positions for the final drawing.

It does not matter if I load as dwg / dxf or go back a few versions.

I have isolated these layers from by drawing and pasted them into a new drawing at the base coordinates, but this still seems to lose the repositioning when imported into the geopackage.

Weirdly, the rotation is correct, but it is not translated away from 0,0.

Is there some further step I can take in my drawing to make sure that any block references and translations are removed from my drawing, and the positions are more explicit before import to QGIS and it appears correctly located?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was just being lazy.  Exploding all the blocks partially worked.

Enough detail of the object in the lines layer of the drawing has imported correctly for my needs.

Anything with a bit of curve on it in the polylines layer still does not work, much of the curve is correct but there are still spurious connector lines going to 0,0, which in this case I can live with.  perhaps i could just delete all the features at 0,0.

(These layers were similarly corrupted when they loaded around 0,0, just the spurious lines headed towards the object centre rather than 5000km away to the equator.)

The drawing with exploded blocks is more than double the size and takes more than double the time to load, but thems the breaks.